# Binding datagrid comboboxcolumn WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, combobox

I have a problem when I try to bind my combobox col.

I have 2 DataSet tables and i want the combo box to show the values of 1 DataSet table but the selected index will be taken from the other DataSet.

Example :

1.Material DataSet with Id col and UnitID col that represet the unit this material weight is calculated.

2.Units DataSet With Id col and Name

The datagrid will show the Material dataset details ( id as textbox col and unitID as comboBox col)

I want my datagrid combobox col to show all Units Names in the combobox option and the selected item will be the one with the index equals to the material UnitID.

I succeeded to show all my units names as the combobox options with :

```
cmb.ItemsSource = DS.Units.ToList

cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "EnglishName"
```

But was unable to specify the SelectedValuePath and SelectedValueBinding at the right way.

Comment: Can you show your code and the place, where is error. It will be easear to understand

Comment: Still not very clear. As I know, in combobox you can show 1 item at a time. For this you can use SelectedValue or SelectedIndex.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your code to show your data structures and your attempts so far. Also specify clearly what results and errors you received.

Comment: Hello All, I'll try to do what was advised to me with the join of 2 DataSets into one. Sasha, it's not a regular ComboBox, it's a comboboxcolumn item and it does not have ( as far as i know ) a selectedIndex property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One data sources can be used for multiple combo boxes however two data sources can't bind to one control. Instead we can use LINQ to combine these data sources and assign resulted data source to combo box.

```
DataTable material= ds.Tables["Material"];
DataTable units= ds.Tables["Units"];

var query =
    from m in material.AsEnumerable()
    join u in units.AsEnumerable()
    on m.Field<int>("Column1") equals
        u.Field<int>("Column1")
select new
    {
        Text =
            u.Field<string>("EnglishName"),
        Value =
            m.Field<int>("MaterialID")
    };

cmb.ItemsSource = query.ToList();

cmb.DisplayMemberPath = "Text";
cmb.SelectedValuePath = "Value"
```